# Localization on varieties with toric singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, localization

Is there a written version of Atiyah-Bott localization formula for varieties/manifolds with toric singularities? More precisely, suppose $F$ is a fixed locus of a torus action $\mathbb{T}={\mathbb{C}^*}^m$ on $X$, that is smooth itself but has a normal cone $N$ whose fibers are modeled on an affine toric variety $Y_{\sigma}$ given by some cone $\sigma\subset \mathbb{R}^k$. In the smooth case $Y_\sigma\cong \mathbb{C}^k$, $N\to F$ is a rank $k$ vector bundle, and the localization contributaion of the fixed locus $F$ is 
$$
1/e_{\mathbb{T}}(N),
$$
where $e_{\mathbb{T}}(N)$ is the equivariant Euler class of the normal bundle $N$.

What is this factor when $Y_{\sigma}$ is singular?

Comment: Hello Mohammad, I hope that you are doing well.  Are you consindering only finite quotient singularities that arise on a toric variety (i.e., Abelian finite quotient singularities)?  Or are you considering more general toric singularities.  For "orbifolds", you can consult Melissa Liu's contribution to the Handbook of Moduli.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks. Not just orbifolds. I want to use localization on moduli spaces of log curves. Potentially, any affine toric variety $Y_{\sigma}$ (corresponding to some rational convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^k$) can arise as the normal cone of some stratum. Orbifold case does not suffice.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the factor you are asking about is often called the *equivariant multiplicity* of $X$ along the fixed component $F$.  The best source for this is Brion's paper "Equivariant Chow groups for torus actions" (*Transformation Groups*, 1997), available here:

https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/sites/default/files/ref_365.pdf

(Look at Section 4, and also at Section 5 which gives formulas for toric singularities.)  There is also this paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00076, which puts things in a more general context and makes the connection with the Atiyah-Bott formula a bit more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I will go through these. I wonder how much of these can be generalized to the original differential geometry setup of Morse-Bott by allowing manifolds with singularities modeled on toric varieties.